# C# Json Reverse Type All Fields

Tags: c#, json

Появилась проблема, Имеются **ТЕСТ-кейсы**, которые мы автоматизируем, соответственно у нас по дефолту есть кейс, предположим у нас есть json **`{"str": 2, "str2": "2"}`**, все что было int, станет string и наоборот (***в основном только эти типы данных используются***),
 все бы хорошо и в этом случае от ненужной десериализации и дублирования кода в формате классов и полей спасали анонимные типы,
 но сейчас же тела запросов стали невероятно гигантскими и и использовать в данном случае анонимные типы просто нецелесообразно, а при десериализации по факту будет дублирование кода на 200+ строк.
Написал метод, который вроде как должен переконвертить наш json

```
public static string ConvertTypes<T>(T data)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var item in data.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (item.PropertyType.Name == "String")
                {
                    dict.Add(item.Name, long.Parse(item.GetValue(data).ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(data).ToString());
                }
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
        }
```

Но пока есть проблема, нужно реализовать логику работы со вложенностями в данном методе.

`File.ReadAllText` также не особо подойдут, так требуется опционально получить некоторое поле и присвоить ему значение.
Подскажите варианты решения проблемы.

Comment: "все что было int, станет string и наоборот" честно говоря, совершенно не понятно что и зачем вам надо сделать .. можете привести четкий пример и указать что в нем избыточно?

Comment: Можно [вообще без десереализации](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670028/12888024) распарсить. Хотя если у вас древний .NET (вы используете старый добрый JSON.NET), то этот способ не для вас. :( `нужно реализовать логику работы со вложенностями` - рекурсия же.

Comment: А вообще, раз уж JSON.NET, почему бы не написать [свой конвертер](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm), который сериализует данные по вашим правилам без вот этого вот всего.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, которое мне подошло и довольно близко к моей проблеме, возможно кому то понадобиться, в данном случае нет необходимости прибегать к рефлексии, можно решить через **JToken**:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JsonRecursiveDescent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json =
            @"[
                {
                    ""X"":
                    {
                        ""Title"":""foo"",
                        ""xxxx"":""xxxx""
                    }
                },
                {
                    ""Y"":
                    {
                        ""ZZ"":
                        {
                            ""Title"":""bar"",
                            ""xxxx"":""xxxx""
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]";

            JToken node = JToken.Parse(json);

            WalkNode(node, n =>
            {
                JToken token = n["Title"];
                if (token != null && token.Type == JTokenType.String)
                {
                    string title = token.Value<string>();
                    Console.WriteLine(title);
                }
            });
        }

        static void WalkNode(JToken node, Action<JObject> action)
        {
            if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                action((JObject)node);

                foreach (JProperty child in node.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    WalkNode(child.Value, action);
                }
            }
            else if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                foreach (JToken child in node.Children())
                {
                    WalkNode(child, action);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```